# How to change the following graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have the following tikz picture I created:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto=left,every node/.style={circle,thick,minimum size=5pt}]

      \draw node (n1) at (20,6) {X};
      \draw node (n2) at (9,6)  {Y};

      \draw (n1) -- (n2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to make a few changes. First, I want the node to be a filled-in circular black dot, not too big (perhaps half of the width of the text next to the node) -- just like you would expect when drawing a graph. I couldn't get it to work, no matter what I did, the "dot" was quite big or in this version -- is not there at all. Rescaling re-scaled the whole thing to be small.

I would also like to add a label to the edge.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, @Jubobs. I already got a good response, but I edited the question to add the headers.

Comment: That's much better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \node[label=west:X,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] (n1) at (0,0) {};
  \node[label=east:Y,circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] (n2) at (1,0) {};
  \draw (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]